# Unity Web Player for Ubuntu?

Tags: unity-web-player

There are various apps on the internet that require the use of Unity Web Player and am rather curious if I could find a way around it to make it work.

I tried the following as only these I found:

1. Enabling the "unity 3d plugin" after installing Pipelight using instructions from [their website](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html)
2. Installing Firefox in Wine and while running it using Wine the Unity Web Player

The one with which I got the closest to the wanted result was the second one: it loads normally when opening an app that requires it, but fails when up to 99% because it is unable to update.

Any solution?

Comment: _"The **Unity Webplayer is no longer supported**. We provide this download link to the last build for convenience, but be aware that the **Unity Webplayer has been deprecated** and will not get any further update. If you want to deliver Unity made content via web browser we recommend you **use WebGL**."_

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

then

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

then

```
go to firefox
open menu-addons-plugins-unity player
click always activate
```

Done!

Comment: Not working in here -> 15.04

Comment: This never works -_-

Comment: linux mint 17.2/ not working

Comment: `~$ sudo pipelight-plugin --update`
`FIXME: Update functionality is currently disabled.`

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to change my answer completely.

---

As of today, the [Pipelight Project](http://pipelight.net) has been discontinued.

This is an excerpt from their home page:

> Pipelight will not suddenly stop working, but you will not receive any further updates. As a result all enabled plugins (e.g. Silverlight/Flash) stay at the same version and do not get any security fixes. This might be a security thread for your system and we therefore recommend to remove Pipelight using the package manager of your distribution.

While the latest change to the [stable branch](https://bitbucket.org/mmueller2012/pipelight/) was "Update of Silverlight to version 5.1.50901.0", I need it just for installing the "Unity web player" which wouldn't install in my Ubuntu 16.10 O.S., so I can't consider no more Pipelight as a solution for Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this may not work on recent Firefox builds.*

1. Install Pipelight:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
   sudo pipelight-plugin --update
   sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
   sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
   ```
2. Then install the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) add-on.
3. Add Windows Firefox user agent at *User Agent Switcher* → *Options* → *New* → *New User Agent*. Then add

   ```
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1
   ```

   into the "User Agent" Field.
4. Then Restart Firefox and test using http://randomationmedia.com/vehicletestweb.html