# How to install unity web player on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity-web-player

I want to know how to install unity web player for ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit version as I am not able to access many of the online apps and they recommend me to download unity web player.

Can I get a simple procedure to download it?

Comment: Are you talking of the Ubuntu browser ([Oxide](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=196)) which is used to run web apps like in http://askubuntu.com/questions/227897/what-are-the-different-unity-web-apps-that-are-available or something else?

Comment: @muru i am talking about mozilla and chrome

Comment: DUPE: http://askubuntu.com/q/425317/62483

Answer (score 11):

A solution could be to use Pipelight:

Here how to install Pipelight on Ubuntu: http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Here how to activate the Unity Web Player Plugin: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Running_Unity_Web_Player_on_Linux_using_Pipelight

```
#!/bin/bash

#FDS-Team: Pipelight Project
#Tomasz Zackiewicz, Pipelight.sh


#update the checksum of Unity3D Web Player
sudo pipelight-plugin --update

#for Firefox, clear the plugin cache
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins

#enabling Unity3D Web Player
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

Comment: Sames command than the mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/498915/62483) :)

Comment: enabled in firefox ubuntu, but still doesn't work

Comment: This does not seem to work in newer versions of Firefox, may be the ones that came out after 2014