# How to install Unity Web Player in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity-web-player

How I can install Unity Web Player in system Linux 14.04 LTS 64-bit Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: look also http://askubuntu.com/questions/425317/unity-web-player-for-ubuntu/498915#498915

Answer (score 1):

When you visit the official site https://unity3d.com/webplayer you can notice the following message:

> UNITY WEB PLAYER
>
> The Unity Web Player can be downloaded to run browser-based Windows
> and Mac games and apps made with Unity. Unfortunately the Unity Web
> Player is not supported for the device you are currently using.

And since I'm using Ubuntu, so in simple This will not work native in Ubuntu, or any other Linux distribution .

#### Now could it be installed in Wine?

Just visiting the [wine tests site](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13269)  shows you can install 4.3.3f and newest in Linux systems using wine.

The test done on Fedora 19 x86_64. Now you can take a look to try for ubuntu.

#### So How to Install it using wine

1. downloaded & installed Firefox (tested with 33.0.2)
2. downloaded & installed Unity Web Player (full version) from [here](http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/UnityWebPlayerFull.exe)

Answer (score 0):

From the PIPELIGHT website:

> Pipelight is a wrapper for using Windows plugins in Linux browsers and
>   therefore giving you the possibility to access services which are
>   otherwise not available for Linux users. Typical examples of such
>   services are Netflix and Amazon Instant, which both use the
>   proprietary browser plugin Silverlight. These services cannot normally
>   be used on Linux since this plugin is only available for Windows, and
>   the only open source alternative (Moonlight) is lacking support for
>   DRM.
>
> Pipelight helps you access these services by using the original
>   Silverlight plugin directly in your browser, all while giving you a
>   better hardware acceleration and performance than a virtual machine.
>   Besides Silverlight, you can also use a variety of other plugins that
>   are supported by Pipelight. Take a look at the installation page for a
>   complete list.
>
> Pipelight uses a patched wine version to provide a windows environment
>   to the plugins, but you do not need to worry about this as Pipelight
>   will take care of installing, configuring and updating all supported
>   plugins. From the perspective of the browser these plugins will behave
>   just like any other normal Linux plugin after you have enabled them.

Just go to http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html and follow their instructions (which may vary over time), depending of your Linux distro and the packages (plugins) you want to install.

NOTE: As of today, latest version (Release v0.2.8) hasn't been updated since 10 Dec 2014, so the project has been quite still since then (2 years).